# How to handle rating bar with recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have a recylerview with a rating bar on each row and a submit button for each ratinbar. In which section of the adapter would I place the listener for this? I plan on storing the ratings in an SQLite table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the listener for the submit button I would put it in the onBindViewHolder

`@Override
        public void 
    onBindViewHolder(com.example.app.RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int 
    position) {
       Button submitBtn = holder.submitBtn;
       submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //do stuff here
         }`